# EF5 Code First Migrations - DB Init running over and over

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Got this weird thing going on with my new EF5 Code First app that's leveraging new new migrations support. One thing that I'm seeing is that the database seeding routine is running on the initial DB load, but what's strange is that it seems to run again after the app hasn't run in a while. Is this to be expected? What's the best way to keep this from happening?

I get the whole .AddOrUpdate(), but still seems odd to have this run more than when the app first ran and created the DB schema. Ideas?

Comment: Where did you put your database seeding? Seeding in migrations runs again every time the database is migrated.

Comment: The seeding is called from my Configuration.Seed() method and in the constructor it's setting the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled property to true. I understood the same thing (they are run when the DB is migrated), but don't understand why it's migrating every time when the schema hasn't changed (verified by only one record in the __Migrations table).

Comment: I'm noticing the same behavior on Azure.  The strange thing is the .AddOrUpdate doesn't seem like it should insert the same records (different only by the PK ID that sql automatically creates for them when they're inserted).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the expected behavior. The Seed method runs even when there are no schema changes to apply.

If you have a heavy amount of work going on in the Seed method and want more control, you could do something like add an app setting to the project's .config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="seedDatabase" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then check for the setting in the Seed method.

```
protected override void Seed(BarDb context)
{
    if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seedDatabase"] == "true")
    {
        // ... seed logic
    }            
}
```

Comment: So... im a bit confused them. What are the initializers for them? If the seed runs all the time, seems like the initializers are duped from the seed method....

Comment: It is confusing, partly because initializers were around before migrations. But, an initializer would always run for a given context type and can drop and create databases. I think of Migrations as more schema oriented and migrations only run when you tell them to run, like by using update-database from the PM console or by using the MigrateDatabseToLatestVersion initializer, which since it is an initializer would always run the migrations. If I am using migrations I wouldn't Seed from an initializer. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So it would seem to me that with Code First Migrations, the only real use for initializers is for automated testing where you can drop & reseed the DB easily. Otherwise, seems like duped functionality... is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that having `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` set to true in the Configuration, will trigger migrations every time the App Start (that is probably why you see that behaviour when the app has not run for a while).

Problem is that then the Migrations code will run the seed even if there was nothing to migrate. I would use a solution similar to @OdeToCode but I would rather have my check done using the DB itself (something like test if the table is empty etc. etc.)

Indeed, the new `Enable-Migrations` command will set the `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to false in the generated `Configuration.cs` file.

Initializers are indeed another form of setting up the DB and as you rightly say they are more useful in a testing/prototyping context that allows you to reset the DB to a known state each time. It looks like duplicated functionality but with different purposes: in a production DB I would not use one of the pre-baked Initializers.